# How to create a method for each element in a list with angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have a list in angularjs

```
   $scope.URLList = [
  {url:'http://www.facebook.com', title : 'facebook'},{url:'http://www.twitter.com', title : 'twitter'}];
```

In my html :

```
  p(ng-repeat='url in URLList')
          a(href="{{url.url}}")       
            span {{url.title}} {{url.number}}
```

Number is not yet define. I need to do this for calculate it :

I would like a method like :

```
  $scope.URLList[where item.url=link].number = function(){
    item.number=1;
    });
  }
```

and call it after

```
     $scope.URLList.push({url:'http://test.com,title:'test'});
```

In advance thanks.

Comment: Odd request. Can you please explain x and not y? What do you really need?

Comment: I would like to call a calculation for each element in a list, and push resulting calculation as a data if it's possible.

Comment: I may be wrong, but don't you want `ng-href="url.url"` in your links?

Comment: Also, you should inject and use the Angular `$http` service rather than jQuery ajax. `$http` will automatically run a digest cycle to update your scope properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't get exactly what you need but to execute a function on an element in ng-repeat you can do something like this

```js
myController = function($scope) {
  $scope.items = [{
    text: "a",
    num: 1
  }, {
    text: "b",
    num: 2
  }, {
    text: "c",
    num: 3
  }];
  $scope.addOne = function(item) {
    item.num += 1;
    
  }
  $scope.items.push({text: "z",num:4});
};
myController.$inject = ["$scope"];
angular.module("myApp", [])
  .controller("myController", myController);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">
  <div ng-repeat="item in items" ng-init="addOne(item)">{{item.text}} :: {{item.num}}</div>
</div>
```

as you see you can pass the object to the function and deal with it ,,

but if you want to iterate over the list of objects you can always use

angular.forEach(items,function(item){ item +=1;} );

Comment: Hi. It's close. Are there any way to do call this method just after : $scope.URLList.push({text:'a',number:3});

Comment: you want to call the function for all the items in list or for the new items only ?

Comment: I've added a directive to the span ng-init ,, ng-init will execute the expression passed to it when the item is added to the list ,, please check the snippet and tell me if it is what you want